# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined, js engine: hermes and WARN Could not find Fiber with id "26"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-dom, react-devtools, react-native-hermes

on debugging the react-native app using flipper,
throwing error related to
*ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined, js engine: hermes*
** WARN  Could not find Fiber with id "26"
WARN  Could not find Fiber with id "25"
**

also pointed **path file** ->> node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/backend.js

and the code is below

`function initialize() { canvas = window.document.createElement('canvas'); canvas.style.cssText = "\n xx-background-color: red;\n xx-opacity: 0.5;\n bottom: 0;\n left: 0;\n pointer-events: none;\n position: fixed;\n right: 0;\n top: 0;\n z-index: 1000000000;\n "; var root = window.document.documentElement; root.insertBefore(canvas, root.firstChild); }`

I also raise this issue on [react-github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/26045#issue-1556502278) and [react-native github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35958#issue-1556258460)

Also, tried with currentWindow (that is define on the same file) but didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AhmedSbai 
 there's problem with the initialize function as "window.document.createElement('canvas')" unable to createElement once the hermes engine is enabled with using flipper. On running the application using flipper it directly points there.